# Any ideas how to find this error: python "double free or corruption"?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

i have a old Python application which runs with Python 2.7 and PyQT4.

The applications keeps crashing in rare cases. Unfortunately i neither know which code-part causes the crash nor how to reproduce it.

I only know it happens sometimes and this is the error:

*** Error in `python': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000004044270 ***

does anyone have an idea, what could cause this?

Comment: Both Qt4 and PyQt4 are obsolete libraries which are no longer supported. And [very soon](https://pythonclock.org/), the same will be true for Python-2.7.

Comment: Yes, i know. Unfortunately i can't upgrade PyQT and Python. Nevertheless it would be create to find this error.

Comment: Then provide an [mcve].